# Create concrete version of sealed generic delegate

Tags: c#, python.net

I would like to do the following:

```
public class ObjectReadEventHandler : EventHandler<ObjectReadEventArgs> { };
```

I cannot do so because EventHandler<> is sealed. Does anyone know of a workaround I can use to make a concrete version of EventHandler<>? I need this because I suspect that Python.NET cannot handle EventHandler<> as a method parameter.

UPDATE:

Essentionally, I want to do this:

```
ObjectReadEventHandler = EventHandler<ObjectReadEventArgs>
```

So that later I can do this:

```
public void AddObjectHandler(string ID, ObjectReadEventHandler handler)
```

The reason I want to do this is because I suspect it will provide a workaround to an issue I am having when using this library in Python.NET.

Comment: Can't you just use `EventHandler<ObjectReadEventArgs>`?

Comment: `EventHandler<T>` is a delegate, not a class. And delegates are sealed.

Comment: `EventHandler<T>` is a delegate type. You can't inherit from delegate type. If you create a delegate it is implicitly done by the compiler.

Comment: Why can't you just use `public delegate void ObjectReadEventHandler(object sender, ObjectReadEventArgs e);` which is equivalent to `EventHandler<ObjectReadEventArgs>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public delegate void ObjectReadEventHandler(
    object sender, ObjectReadEventArgs args);
```

This is how you declare delegates. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/17sde2xt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**REGARDING UPDATE:** Delegates are convertible, you can of course assign one to another if they have same signature (parameters and return value + some variance to be correct). Delegates are essentially derived from [`MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is something like list of method+object.